# how to get Bootstrap affix to recalculate on window resize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get the affix function to recalculate the top and bottom position if the window changes in size? at the moment it just sticks with the original values it is given after document ready. This causes overlapping when changing the screen size. I tried wrapping the function in (window).on('load', ) etc. but this caused the function to not work at all.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#sb_image').affix({
        offset: {
            top: function() {
                return(this.top = jQuery('#fullhead_wrap').outerHeight(true))
            },
            bottom: function() {
              return (this.bottom = jQuery('#ft_cont').outerHeight(true))
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#sb_image').affix('checkPosition')` per the documentation? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#affix-methods

Comment: @RobertC Yeah. I tried just placing that bit of code below and above the affix function it did nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of googling and experimenting I have figured out how to get affix to be responsive. Firstly the reason I could not wrap my code in a window resize function was because I had set a data-spy="affix" attribute on my affixed element. This is not needed if you are using jQuery. Secondly if you set the bottom and top values using this.top = or this.bottom = it will take the first value it is given and never override this value even if the value has changed. heres what I ended up with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
        jQuery('#sb_image').affix({
            offset: {
                top: function() {
                    return(jQuery('#fullhead_wrap').outerHeight(true))
                },
                bottom: function() {
                  return (jQuery('#ft_cont').outerHeight(true))
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```